# TextBox doesnot exist in current context

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I don't use Master Content Page on anything . I have a simple aspx page .
Still it shows

> The name 'txtFirstName' does not exist in the current context

My MarkUp

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">

    protected void txtFirstName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string firstName = txtFirstName.Text;
    }
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtFirstName_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Even OnTextChanged event is firing properly.I don't understand, what could be the issue ?

Other similar posts i searched didn't help much.

Please Suggest .....

Answer (score 3):

You must have a `form` tag with `runat="Server"`..

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" text="" AutoPostBack="True"/>
</form>

protected void txtFirstName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string firstName = txtFirstName.Text;
    }
```

**Note**:- 1) Place Script inside the `<head>` tag..

```
   2) Add `AutoPostBack="True"` to the textbox..
```

Comment: @user3487944, what do you mean by `not working`? Still the same error, or a different problem now?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" text="" />
</form>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_textbox.asp

```
protected void txtFirstName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        string firstName = btn.Text;
    }
```

Comment: In the event handler `this` refers to the page, not the control. The `sender` parameter is a reference to the control.